# References and How They Work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pointers, reference

Consider these object and reference to it.

```js
const
 foobar = { foo: 'bar' }
,ref = foobar;
```

Let say `foobar` itself has address `0xF00BA9` and it points to `0x0B1EC7` (actual object `{ foo: 'bar' }`), will `ref` point to `0xF00BA9` or directly to `0x0B1EC7`?

---

```js
ref.foo;
// &ref > &foobar > foobar object > foo
// or &ref > foobar object > foo
```

Comment: The variable itself doesnot have any value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value type decides whether the assignment is by value (for primitive types like boolean, number etc) or by reference (object / array).
So `foobar` itself doesn't have an address, it's just a pointer to the object's address.
`ref` will point to the same object in memory (it will contain the same pointer to the address). So you could say they both point to `0x0B1EC7`.

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600).